# How to service a vehicles electrical system?

Tags: electrical, service

While I have a good knowledge on general service procedures for a vehicles engine, suspension, exhaust and other usual systems, I'm unsure of how to keep a vehicles electrical system in top-notch.

My question is, does the electrical system require routine maintenance, and if so, what tasks would it involve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not much, but things to check include:

1) battery terminals - clean, tight and some protection ie petroleum jelly works well on lead/acid batteries

2) all cables (easily visible) are not rubbing or chafing anywhere

3) all bulbs / lights function.

Used to have distributors on the list and brush height & rear bearing to oil in dynamos etc but times change.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have the required tools, I would add:

4) Load testing the battery
5) Testing alternator output

and no tools required...

6) Making sure the top and sides of the battery itself are clean to prevent stray voltage loss